# Django: cannot get an Model instance from ForwardManyToOneDescriptor (ForeignKey)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-signals

I have the following code in `accounts/signals/__init__.py`:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from orders.models import Order
from accounts.models import Balance

@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def update_referral_balance(sender, **kwargs):
    if len(sender.user.referrals_set.all()):
        # TODO: Add referralTransaction
        new_referral_revenue = sender.user.referrals_set.get().revenue
        revenue_from_trade = \
            new_referral_revenue - sender.old_referral_revenue

        balance, created = \
            Balance.objects.get(user=sender.user, currency=sender.currency)
        balance.balance += revenue_from_trade
        balance.save()
```

Now, when running tests I am getting the following

```
error:======================================================================
    ERROR: test_orders_with_approved_payments (payments.tests.test_views.PaymentReleaseTestCase)
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/pipeline/source/payments/tests/test_views.py", line 75, in setUp
        self.order.save()
      File "/pipeline/source/orders/models.py", line 63, in save
        super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/safedelete/models.py", line 64, in save
        super(Model, self).save(**kwargs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 708, in save
        force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 745, in save_base
        update_fields=update_fields, raw=raw, using=using)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py", line 192, in send
        response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
      File "/pipeline/source/accounts/signals/__init__.py", line 9, in update_referral_balance
        if len(sender.user.referral_set.all()):
    AttributeError: 'ForwardManyToOneDescriptor' object has no attribute 'referral_set'
```

And indeed, when running through it in debugger, I see that the `sender.user` attribute is something of instance `ForwardManyToOneDescriptor`:

```
ipdb> pprint(sender.__dict__['user'].__dict__)
{'cache_name': '_user_cache',
 'field': <django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignKey: user>}
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My `Order` Model:

class Order(TimeStampedModel, SoftDeletableModel, UniqueFieldMixin):
    USD = "USD"
    RUB = "RUB"
    EUR = "EUR"

```
BUY = 1
SELL = 0
TYPES = (
    (SELL, 'SELL'),
    (BUY, 'BUY'),
)

# Todo: inherit from BTC base?, move lengths to settings?
order_type = models.IntegerField(choices=TYPES, default=BUY)
amount_cash = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
amount_btc = models.DecimalField(max_digits=18, decimal_places=8)
currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
payment_window = models.IntegerField(default=settings.PAYMENT_WINDOW)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='orders')
is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_released = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_failed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
unique_reference = models.CharField(
    max_length=settings.UNIQUE_REFERENCE_LENGTH, unique=True)
admin_comment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
payment_preference = models.ForeignKey('payments.PaymentPreference',
                                       default=None,
                                       null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_on']

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.unique_reference = \
        self.gen_unique_value(
            lambda x: get_random_string(x),
            lambda x: Order.objects.filter(unique_reference=x).count(),
            settings.UNIQUE_REFERENCE_LENGTH
        )
    self.convert_coin_to_cash()

    if 'is_completed' in kwargs and\
            kwargs['is_completed'] and\
            not self.is_completed:
        self.old_referral_revenue = \
            self.user.referral_set.get().revenue

    super(Order, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def convert_coin_to_cash(self):
    self.amount_btc = Decimal(self.amount_btc)
    queryset = Price.objects.filter().order_by('-id')[:2]
    price_sell = [price for price in queryset if price.type == Price.SELL]
    price_buy = [price for price in queryset if price.type == Price.BUY]

    # Below calculation affect real money the client pays
    assert all([len(price_sell),
                price_sell[0].price_usd,
                price_buy[0].price_rub,
                price_buy[0].price_eur])

    assert all([len(price_buy),
                price_buy[0].price_usd,
                price_buy[0].price_rub,
                price_buy[0].price_eur])

    # TODO: Make this logic more generic,
    # TODO: migrate to using currency through payment_preference

    # SELL
    self.amount_cash = Decimal(self.amount_btc)

    if self.order_type == Order.SELL and self.currency.code == Order.USD:
        self.amount_cash *= price_buy[0].price_usd

    elif self.order_type == Order.SELL and self.currency.code == Order.RUB:
        self.amount_cash *= price_buy[0].price_rub

    elif self.order_type == Order.SELL and self.currency.code == Order.EUR:
        self.amount_cash *= price_buy[0].price_eur

    # BUY
    if self.order_type == Order.BUY and self.currency.code == Order.USD:
        self.amount_cash *= price_sell[0].price_usd

    elif self.order_type == Order.BUY and self.currency.code == Order.RUB:
        self.amount_cash *= price_sell[0].price_rub

    elif self.order_type == Order.BUY and self.currency.code == Order.EUR:
        self.amount_cash *= price_sell[0].price_eur

    self.amount_cash = money_format(self.amount_cash)

@property
def is_buy(self):
    return self.order_type

@property
def payment_deadline(self):
    """returns datetime of payment_deadline (creation + payment_window)"""
    # TODO: Use this for pay until message on 'order success' screen
    return self.created_on + timedelta(minutes=self.payment_window)

@property
def expired(self):
    """Is expired if payment_deadline is exceeded and it's not paid yet"""
    # TODO: validate this business rule
    # TODO: Refactor, it is unreasonable to have different standards of
    # time in the DB
    return (timezone.now() > self.payment_deadline) and\
           (not self.is_paid) and not self.is_released

@property
def payment_status_frozen(self):
    """return a boolean indicating if order can be updated
    Order is frozen if it is expired or has been paid
    """
    # TODO: validate this business rule
    return self.expired or \
        (self.is_paid and
         self.payment_set.last() and
         self.payment_set.last().
         payment_preference.
         payment_method.is_internal)

@property
def withdrawal_address_frozen(self):
    """return bool whether the withdraw address can
       be changed"""
    return self.is_released

@property
def has_withdraw_address(self):
    """return a boolean indicating if order has a withdraw adrress defined
    """
    # TODO: Validate this business rule
    return len(self.address_set.all()) > 0

@property
def withdraw_address(self):
    addr = None

    if self.has_withdraw_address:
        addr = self.transaction_set.first().address_to.address

    return addr

def __str__(self):
    return "{} {} {} BTC {} {}".format(self.user.username or
                                       self.user.profile.phone,
                                       self.order_type,
                                       self.amount_btc,
                                       self.amount_cash,
                                       self.currency)
```

Comment: You need to show your Order model.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `sender` argument is the *model class* the signal has connected to. As you can see from the [signals docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/signals/#post-save), in `post_save` the instance is passed in a separate argument unsurprisingly called `instance`.

You should write your handler like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Order)
def update_referral_balance(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if len(instance.user.referrals_set.all()):
```

etc, changing `sender` to `instance` throughout.

Comment: Well documentation is naturally annoyingly long...
I was waiting on this StackOverflow docs project... but it never came